# How do I add an attribute to a filter?

Tags: admin, filter, ce-1.8.1.0

I am trying to get an attribute to the filter in my webshop. I have tried several things in the admin panel, but nothing seems to work.

At the moment there are two attributes in it, profile color and height, but i also want width in it.

The attribute is made with the correct settings. So what now?

Comment: Exactly what 'things' did you try in the admin panel? A bit more info is needed. see here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/attribute-frontend-properties and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PQhITHhWUk and remember to flush your cache and disable compilation

Comment: Basicly the things the two answers told me to do + I added the attribute in the right attribute set.

Comment: Do products using this filter exist, are activated etc? Otherwise the filter won't show; also, did you clear the cache and reindex?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the attribute in the backend and set the value for `Use In Layered Navigation` to `Filterable (with results)` or `Filterable (no results)`. Save and rebuild your indexes.
Do the same for `Use In Search Results Layered Navigation`.

But keep in mind that only dropdown, multiple select and price attributes can be displayed in the filters.

Comment: This was already the case. I copied the settings of the "height" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Login to admin panel and goto  catalog-> attributes -> manage attributes

and click on addattributes button In add attributes properties tab add your attribute code and set all you want necessary fields. For your attribute label or option set under Manage label tab. 
if you want to show this attributes on product view page for filter   **Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** set **Yes** if you created your attribute set for your product select it while adding product.

Comment: I had this done already, still didn't work.
Not sure what you mean with " if you created your attribute set for your product select it while adding product." though.

Comment: Do you created attribute set?

Comment: It was already there. I'm working on a website that already existed. My assignment was to delete one attribute from the filter, and add a different one.

Comment: For that goto->attributes->manage attribute sets-> select your attribute set you used. for adding new one you see your created attribute under __Unassigned Attributes__ section add it.

Comment: I've also done that... that's the reason i came here. (Yes I realize I should've came with a more detailed question.)

Also, when i re-add the attribute that i deleted from that set (dragged it to the Unassigned Attributes), nothing happens.